# How can debug this ASP.net MVC 4 error on temporary files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have developed a MVC 4 web application, and i am getting this error:

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3f2bfc7c\b3a7a1f1\App_Web_evento.cshtml.1daa837f.iofx3fob.0.cs(43): error CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected

In local it works fine, but when i publish and upload changes to the web i get this error.
I have tried to clean the temporary files but i keep getting the error.

How can i debug and solve this error?

Edit: this is the code at line 43

```
public class _Page_Views_sampedros_evento_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<EventoInfo;> {

#line hidden

        public _Page_Views_sampedros_evento_cshtml() {
        }
```

I suppose the error goes for the ";>" part at the end of the first line, but this code is generated automatically, in local it works.

Comment: Have you tried restart IIS? You can also open that file and look at line 43 - maybe there is something what helps you solve your problem.

Comment: @MajoB i have edit the question adding the portion of code at line 43. This code is generated automatically so i dont know what to do with it..

Comment: Restart IIS and clean out the temporary files at the path specified in the error.  Sounds like IIS has cached a bad file and is not letting go.

Comment: I have stopped the site in IIS and cleaned the temporary data and starting it again, but keep getting the error.. i have tried to delete contents of that page, leaving it with blank html and still the same. It seems it doesnt read the new cshtml

Comment: Some ideas? i have changed the name of the view for Event.chtml and changed the controller to show this new View but still have the error, but know on App_web_event.chhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the runtime error is in the temporary files, the error message is telling you that the syntax issue is in your `sampedros/evento.cshtml` or `sampedros_evento.cshtml` view.

Look at any model declarations in that view and see if your using a semicolon to end a statement when you shouldn't. The line probably ends with `EventInfo;` and should just end at `EventInfo`.

Comment: I came across this question while trying to figure out the same problem myself.